# Switching from 'compile' to 'implementation' gives DexPathList Error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to update my dependencies to use the new implementation/api spec instead of compile. This is for a general library I am writing which I then use in my app via jitpack.

When I make the simple switch from compile to implementation I get the following error (just the important bits) when using the library in my app:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions" on path: DexPathList
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding and it does not help. The second I switch back to compile calls everything works just fine.

I'll note that the library will build just fine in all cases.

The following usage works (though warns me that compile will be deprecated):

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0"
    compile 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    compile "com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

The following gives the above error (also gives the error if I use api instead of implementation):

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

I'll also add that if I just switch the glide to compile then it gives the same error but about a different dependency. Can anyone help me figure this out? I could just keep compile for now but I want to update this.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of debugging I finally figured it out

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
```

Updating the maven gradle plugin in my library to 2.1 from 1.5 resolved the issue